# Problem using Eager Loading in a Eloquent Model

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading, laravel-5.7, eloquent-relationship

I have 2 models and their relations. The first class is called 'Documento':

```
class Documento extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'documento';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cod_documento';

    public function emisor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Emisor', 'cod_emisor', 'cod_emisor');
    }
}
```

The second one is called 'Emisor':

```
class Emisor extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'emisor';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cod_emisor';

    public function documentos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Documento', 'cod_emisor', 'cod_emisor');
    }
}
```

The models relationship is one-to-many (one emisor has many documents, and one document has only one emisor).

In Thinker, i tryo to get a emisor from a document and this work well:

```
>>> Documento::find(1)->emisor->name
=> "Emisor Name"
```

But when I try to do Eager Loading the emisor in document, that "fails":

```
>>> Documento::find(1)->with('emisor')->count();
=> 94041
```

I expected one result, but the query return 94041 documents.

Why is this happening? How to obtain a one document with nested emisor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap `find()` and `with()`:

```php
$documento = Documento::with('emisor')->find(1);
```

Or use [lazy eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading):

```php
$documento = Documento::find(1)->load('emisor');
```

With an existing model instance:

```php
$documento->load('emisor');
```

You are getting this unexpected result because `Documento::find(1)->with('emisor')` creates a new query that queries *all* `Documento` entries. Hence the total count of `94041`.

Comment: But if I use your first solution in the `show` method in controller (using model binding), return the first document always:
    public function show(Documento $documento) {
        return $documento->with('emisor')->find(1);
    }
```

Comment: Use the second option for model instances: `$documento->load('emisor');`